# Plotly output in Jupyter notebook to be saved when exported as HTML

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, plotly

I want to be able to see my plotly figure when the notebook is saved as HTML.

reproducible example:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
animals=['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys']

fig = go.Figure([go.Bar(x=animals, y=[20, 14, 23])])
fig.show()
```

I understand there are two ways to do this:

1. Static image
2. Interactive HTML code embedded

**Method 1: static**

```
from IPython.display import Image
import plotly.io as pio
img_bytes = pio.to_image(fig, format='png')
Image(img_bytes)
```

or

a markdown cell with:
after saving writing the file to png and running it through an online [base64 converter](https://www.base64-image.de/)

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,CODE_FOLLOWS_HERE" />
```

**Method 2: interactive**

```
fig.write_html("myfile.html")
```

This creates a separate html file with the plot. Is there a way to just write into the notebook maybe?

Is there a way so that when the whole notebook is saved as html the figure appears as an interactive plot?

I couldn't get any of the following to work. They display within my notebook on azure but once saved as html they dont appear.

Comment: Maybe I do not understand your question. But, does `File -> Download as -> HTML (.html)` do the job?

Comment: @sentence When `File -> Download as -> HTML (.html)` plotly outputs aren't embeded

Comment: Are you sure outputs are not embedded? I can see them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually saving the output as a screenshot.png then uploading it using

```
from IPython.display import Image
Image(filename="screenshot.png")
```

this way shows up when the notebook is saved as HTML. However, this is only a static solution.